# Are there any generally acceptable UART best practices when it comes to hardware design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, uart, best-practice

Are there any generally acceptable UART best practices when it comes to hardware.

Hi, I am trying to design a PCB that uses UART to communicate between two microcontrollers. Are there any generally agreed upon best practices that can optimize performance further that can be implemented on the hardware level.

Something along the lines of pull up/down resistors, resistors in series, TVS diodes

Comment: That would depend on many factors, that may not be even UART specific. Will they be on same PCB? How far apart? How fast they have to communicate? Do they use RS232 voltage levels or logic levels? Is there only TX and RX or handshake pins as well? Will they get power and boot at the same time, or will either be turned off at any point? Also, why would there be two microcontrollers instead of one larger one so they don't have to communicate?

Comment: 1. They are on two seperate PCBs, thay are about 20cm apart. 
2. They will be using 5V logic levels to communicate.
3. Thay will not boot at the same time. One will serve as the main controller, and will turn the other controller off when it is not needed.
4. Two are needed because the second one is integrated in a OTS component i'm using.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. This is new information and should be edited into your Question. Otherwise, readers have to piece it all together to understand the full question. Thanks.